# DATETIME en MySQL no registra correctamente la fecha

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, mysqli, datetime

tengo el siguiente problema. Uso la librería **datetimepicker** para seleccionar una fecha en un formulario y registrarlo en la base de datos. El problema es que quiero registrar la fecha en el formato de MySQL pero no me registra la hora, es decir en el formulario selecciono el formato de esta manera 2017-09-28 11:32:34 pero en la base de datos solo me registra 2017-09-28 00:00:00

Cabe destacar que hice un var_dump en PHP y si me imprime la fecha con todo y hora seleccionada, entonces no entiendo porque me causa el error, comentar también que el tipo de dato que uso en MYSQL es el DATETIME

[image: Informacion de las filas]

[image: Muestra el error(detalle)]

```
//Seccion Insertar

if($page=='create'){
    if($_POST) {
        $validator = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());
        if(isset($_SESSION['u_usuario']['PK_idUsuario'])){
            #Obtener el Usuario que inició sesion para saber quién está manipulando los tickets.
            $usuarioCreado = $_SESSION['u_usuario']['PK_idUsuario'];
            $fechaVencimiento = $_POST["fechaFinal"];

            $color = $_POST["colorNota"];
            $regDescripcion = $_POST["regDescripcion"];
            $status = 1;

            $sql="INSERT INTO recordatorio (fechaVencimiento, descripcion, status, color, FK_idUsuario) VALUES ('$fechaVencimiento','$regDescripcion','$status', '$color', '$usuarioCreado')";              
            $query = $con->query($sql);         
            var_dump($sql);

            if($query === TRUE ) {
                $validator['success'] = true;
                $validator['messages'] = "Recordatorio creado correctamente";               

            } else {
                $validator['success'] = false;
                $validator['messages'] = "Error al crear el recordatorio";                  
            }
        }else{
            $validator['success'] = false;
            $validator['messages'] = "Sesion caducada, recargue la página e inicie sesion nuevamente para registrar un nuevo recordatorio.";
        }

        $con->close();
        echo json_encode($validator);
    }
}


#Seccion Recuperar
else if($page=='read'){
    $output = array('data' => array());
    $query = $con->query("SELECT * FROM recordatorio WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY fechaVencimiento ASC");

    $x = 1;

    while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
        #Almacenar los datos en el arreglo.
        $btnEvento ='
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaleditarRecordatorio" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" title="Editar" onclick="editarRecordatorio('.$row['PK_idRecordatorio'].')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>
        <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modaleliminarRecordatorio" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Eliminar" onclick="eliminarRecordatorio('.$row['PK_idRecordatorio'].')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>                
        ';


        $descripcion = '<p style="color:#0088cc">'.$row['descripcion'].'</p>';
        $output['data'][] = array(
            $x,
            $descripcion,
            $row['fechaInicio'],
            $row['fechaVencimiento'],
            $btnEvento
        );
    $x++;
    }
    $con->close();
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes escrita la consulta de inserción? ¿Cómo creas la variable relativa a la fecha/hora que le pasas al `INSERT`?

Comment: Hago la inserción de esta manera: **$query = $con->query("INSERT INTO recordatorio (fechaVencimiento, descripcion, status) VALUES  ('$fechaVencimiento','$regDescripcion','$status')");**   y recupero el valor del campo así: **$fechaVencimiento = $_POST["fechaFinal"];** cuando hago un _var_dump($fechaVencimiento )_ si me muestra de forma correcta pero al insertar me causa el problema.

Comment: Por favor, podrías ejecutar esta consulta en MySQL: `DESCRIBE nombre-de-la-tabla;`  y añadir la información del campo `fechaVencimiento` a la pregunta. También pon toda la query en una variable: `$sql="INSERT INTO recordatorio (fechaVencimiento, descripcion, status) VALUES ('$fechaVencimiento','$regDescripcion','$status')";` e imprime la variable: `echo $sql;`. Coloca ambas cosas en la pregunta para que nos ayudes a encontrar una solución a este problema.

Comment: He hecho lo que me ha solicitado!, espero pueda orientarme.

Comment: Porque salen 2 fechas en un campo? o son diferentes?

Comment: El primero es para almacenar fecha de registro  pero uso el   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  de mysql , la segunda fecha es para el vencimiento del registro y es la que me causa ese error porque lo capturo del formulario.

Comment: Por favor, pon el código de PHP donde recuperas los valores y haces el `INSERT`. Quién sabe si hay una manipulación extraña.  Para salir de dudas, guarda la instrucción SQL en una variable: `$sql="INSERT INTO recordatorio (fechaVencimiento, descripcion, status) VALUES ('$fechaVencimiento','$regDescripcion','$status')";` e imprímela: `echo $sql;` luego pon en la pregunta o en un comentario el resultado.

Comment: He colocado el codigo PHP.

Comment: Correcto, has puesto el código, pero no te has enterado de algo muy importante que te he dicho: **depurar tu cadena `$sql="INSERT INTO recordatorio (fechaVencimiento, descripcion, status, color, FK_idUsuario) VALUES ('$fechaVencimiento','$regDescripcion','$status', '$color', '$usuarioCreado')"; `**. ¿Tú sabes cómo se está creando esa cadena?. Te dije que escribieras esto: `echo $sql;` y que agregaras el resultado de ese `echo` a la pregunta. No el `var_dump`, sino el `echo` para verificar cómo se está enviando la fecha a la base de datos y determinar dónde está el problema.

Comment: Trata tu valor post de esta manera: $fechaVencimiento = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($_POST["fechaFinal"]));

Comment: La consulta de inserción que aparece en la imagen parece correcta. Lo único por lo que podría estar cambiándose la hora a `00:00:00` sería que tuvieras algún disparador o función que modifique todas las horas para ese campo poniéndolas en cero, o alguna configuración por defecto que haga eso, o que realmente no estés verificando el dato que se haya insertado, sino otro dato. No creo que para este caso el problema esté en el código.

Answer (score 1):

El formato de fechas para un campo del tipo datetime en MySQL es:

```
AÑO-MES-DIA HORA:MINUTOS:SEGUNDOS
```

Por lo que tal como te sugiere Mario Alejandro Gonzalez Flore, debes formatear bien tu fecha para la inserción. En tu caso concreto sería cambiar la siguiente línea:

```
$fechaVencimiento = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($_POST["fechaFinal"]));
```

O bien si quieres dejar esa tarea a MySQL:

```
$fechaVencimiento = "STR_TO_DATE(".$_POST["fechaFinal"].", '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s')";
```

Y en dónde dice "%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s" puedes especificar como tienes el formato original.

Decir también que no es buena idea colocar un POST directamente en la SQL sin tratar ya que existe la posibilidad de ataques de SQL Injection, te recomiendo ver el siguiente enlace:

[¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%c3%b3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%c3%b3n-sql-en-php)